# Tasker - turn off wifi IF there's no internet connection

Tags: tasker

i can't figure it out how to do this and all other tutorials are outdated and i have not some options they do (like a check box next to the time to set variable). so please don't mark this question as duplicate.

with that said; i have a profile which turn WiFi on when i unlock my phone. i want that to also ping Google DNS and if it get time out turn WiFi off if not keep the wifi connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a task to ping Google DNS as follows:

Task → Code  → Run Shell

Command: `ping -c 2 8.8.8.8` [Store Output In: `%stdout`] [Continue Task After Error: **checked**]

> `If` `%stdout` ~ *100% packet loss*
>
> google servers unreachable
>
> `Else`
>
> connectivity established
>
> `End If`

[image: IMG:]

Add this to your main task with either keeps wi-fi conection or switches it off.

Credits

[Run shell 'ping' with tasker](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/UziXuzUUZ_k)

Comment: when wifi is on but not connected it give me the message "device connected" how cam i fix that?

Comment: 07.48.07/E Run Shell: %stdout -> %stdout
07.48.07/E Run Shell:  -> 
07.48.07/E Run Shell:  -> 
07.48.07/Shell runBackground ping -c 2 8.8.8.8 root: false timeout: -1
07.48.07/Shell start process-thread ID 813
07.48.07/E add wait type Shell1 time 2147483647
07.48.07/E add wait type Shell1 done
07.48.07/E add wait task
07.48.07/Variables doreplresult: |%stdout| -> |%stdout|
07.48.07/E Error: 2

Comment: This task, produces an error when the device can;t ping, thus you have to tick "continue on error, in the task to prevent this...The flash message "Devie connected"is a customised text just to indicate that it has successfully pinge to google DNS you could replace this text with any useful message to indicate a succssful ping

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the complexity and performance hit of "shelling out", you can do this with Tasker native commands. Use command "http get", then check the HTTP return code in %HTTPRC (or sonething like that:-).

Comment: It would help if you could add a bit more steps making it easy for new Tasker users to follow too. :-)

Comment: Entirely unnecessary; Android has alreadly done an internet connectivity check, plus, your method doesn't account for Captive Portal logins. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### The Quick, Dirty, and 99% Reliable Method

Better yet, simply use AutoTools' Connectivity event **or** action. While I generally don't recommend plug-ins, unless absolutely necessary, AutoTools is definitely an essential.

### The Right Way™

If you want to do it, "the right way," although considerably more convoluted, use the new `Get Network Info` action and check the capabilities, like so:

```
Task: Disconnect Wi-Fi if No Internet

<Pause and allow for network conditions and checks to settle>
A1: Wait [
     MS: 0
     Seconds: 3
     Minutes: 0
     Hours: 0
     Days: 0
     Continue Task After Error:On ]

A2: Get Network Info [
     Continue Task After Error:On ]

<Wi-Fi Connected to AP<br />
<b>AND</b><br />
(Does NOT have internet<br />
<b>OR</b><br />
Has NOT been validated<br />
<b>OR</b><br />
Captive Portal PRESENT)>
A3: If [ %ni_active_types(#?wifi) > 0 & %ni_active_capabilities(#?internet) < 1 | %ni_active_capabilities(#?validated) < 1 | %ni_active_capabilities(#?captive_portal) > 0 ]

    A4: WiFi [
         Set: Off
         Continue Task After Error:On ]

A5: End If
```

*(Scroll to the right at the bottom, in the `If` conditions of `A3`, of the above code block to see where the magic really happens.)*

The above allows for a variety of network scenarios to occur without prematurely judging the state of internet connectivity; namely, Captive Portal logins. It also prevents you from having to manually ping Google.com (which has its own pitfalls).

### ... One Step Further

You could make this much more robust too by associating the above task with a profile that handles things on an event-driven basis when network conditions change, like so:

```
Profile: Wi-Fi: Network Change Detected
Settings: Priority: 20 Enforce: no
    Event: Intent Received [ Action:android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE Cat:None Cat:None Scheme:* Mime Type:* ]


Enter Task: Anon
Settings: Abort Existing Task

Task: Disconnect Wi-Fi if No Internet

<Pause and allow for network conditions and checks to settle>
A1: Wait [
     MS: 0
     Seconds: 3
     Minutes: 0
     Hours: 0
     Days: 0
     Continue Task After Error:On ]

A2: Get Network Info [
     Continue Task After Error:On ]

<Wi-Fi Connected to AP<br />
<b>AND</b><br />
(Does NOT have internet<br />
<b>OR</b><br />
Has NOT been validated<br />
<b>OR</b><br />
Captive Portal PRESENT)>
A3: If [ %ni_active_types(#?wifi) > 0 & %ni_active_capabilities(#?internet) < 1 | %ni_active_capabilities(#?validated) < 1 | %ni_active_capabilities(#?captive_portal) > 0 ]

    A4: WiFi [
         Set: Off
         Continue Task After Error:On ]

A5: End If
```

*(Take special note of the Task Setting of, `Abort Existing Task` since this intent gets fired about 6-12 times whenever there is a network state change and you don't want your Task to be executing at the very beginning of those intents, otherwise network states won't be correct yet.)*

Also, make sure you're not in beginner mode or in Tasky, and ensure all steps have, `Continue on Error` checked.

That is the proper way to detect internet connectivity: by allowing Android to do the heavy-lifting so that ALL scenarios are accounted for.